# Needing to use def to call a check function twice

Tags: python

We're making a Gibberish converter. The user inputs a chosen word and two gibberish lines (each two characters long)  that will replace the vowel in the chosen word.

```
import string

print("English to Gibberish translator")

user = ""

vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"

while user.lower() != "n":


    cons1 = input("Enter your first Gibberish syllable (add * for the vowel substitute): ")
    check = True
    while check:
        for letter in cons1:
            if letter not in string.ascii_letters and letter != "*":
                cons1 = input("Syllable must only contain letters or a wildcard ('*'): ")
                break
        else:
            check = False

    cons2 = input("Enter the second Gibberish syllable (* for vowel substitute): ")
    while check:
        for letter in cons2:
            if letter not in string.ascii_letters and letter != "*":
                cons2 = input("Syllable must only contain letters or a wildcard ('*'): ")
                break
        else:
            check = False
```

As you see there are two check loops that check to see if the user imputed a correct line. We have to use the def function to replace this code and instead call it twice.
How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you ever defined a function before? [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) may be useful to you.

Comment: There is nothing called `def` function,

Answer (score 0):

```
def inputgib(pro):
    val = input(pro)
    valid = string.ascii_letters + ["*"]
    return val if all(c in valid for c in val) else inputgib(pro)
cons1 = inputgib("Enter your first Gibberish syllable (add * for the vowel substitute): ")
cons2 = inputgib("Enter the second Gibberish syllable (* for vowel substitute): ")
```

This recursive function condenses the validation into a generator expression and calls itself again with the same prompt if the line is not valid.